# ShareKit Compile Issue - JSONKit not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sharekit, jsonkit

I have followed the following instructions in order to setup and configure ShareKit: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

When trying to compile my app, I now get the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/app_root_path/Submodules/ShareKit/Classes/ShareKit/Core/Helpers/../../Submodules/JSONKit/Submodules/ShareKit/Submodules/JSONKit/JSONKit.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried reinstalling ShareKit, but cannot solve the problem.

Any suggestions about alleviating the problem will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the submodules as well?

```
cd Submodules/ShareKit
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Check out: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit