# ShareKit PocketAPI.m not found

Tags: sharekit

1. I have downloaded ShareKit project from https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit into a separate "ios_distr" folder
2. I have followed the instruction documented here https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit to add ShareKit into my project. I have double checked that I drag the ShareKit project into my project properly. I have double checked that I've configured all dependancies and targets and linked all necessary libs.
3. I have double checked that I have downloaded all Submodules via git and have added $(SRCROOT)/../MyProjectNameHere/ShareKit/Submodules/** and $(SRCROOT)/../MyProjectNameHere/ShareKit/Classes/** to the "User header search path" of my project target.

Now when I compile my project I get an error message that PocketAPI.m file is not found. When I look at the details of the error message in xCode I find this:

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/angel/Sergey/ios_distr/ShareKit-master/Submodules/Pocket-ObjC-SDK/SDK/PocketAPI.m'

Why does it look for PocketAPI.m file int the "ios_distr" folder and not in my project's "Submodules" folder?

Please advise me how to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have the same problem as I had:
solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383236/sharekit-compile-issue-jsonkit-not-found)

in terminal navigate to [Your project root folder]

then make this commands:

cd Submodules/ShareKit
git submodule init
git submodule update